# add 2 image views to a uiscrollview func every time it is called

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, imageview, addsubview

My swift code below goal is to add 2 image views every time. Ass you can in the gif below only one image view is being added. I just need to add 2 image views. The image views are lastImage and lastImage2. you can see only lastImage is being shown. It seems I can only add 1 imageview when func didclickadd is called.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var  lastImage:UIImageView?
    fileprivate var  lastImage2:UIImageView?

    fileprivate var mainViewBootom:NSLayoutConstraint?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupVIew()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    //MARK: Components
    let scrollView:UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        return sv
    }()

    let mainView:UIView = {
        let uv = UIView()
        uv.backgroundColor = .white
        return uv
    }()

    let btnAdd:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()



    let textField:UITextField = {
        let jake = UITextField()
        return jake

    }()

    //MARK: Setup UI
    func setupVIew() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(btnAdd)
        view.addSubview(textField)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btnAdd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([




            btnAdd.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            btnAdd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
            btnAdd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            btnAdd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),


            //
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),
            //



            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnAdd.topAnchor , constant: -12),
        ])
        btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClickedAdd), for: .touchUpInside)

        scrollView.addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
        ])

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        imgView.backgroundColor  = .red
        mainView.addSubview(imgView)


        let samsam = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 40, height: 100))
        samsam.backgroundColor  = .blue
        mainView.addSubview(samsam)




        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true


        samsam.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        samsam.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        samsam.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        samsam.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
        samsam.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true



        if lastImage != nil {
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).isActive = true
        }else{
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor , constant: 12).isActive = true
        }
        lastImage = samsam
        mainViewBootom = mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 12)
        mainViewBootom!.isActive = true
    }

    @objc func didClickedAdd(){
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20))
        imgView.backgroundColor  = .orange
        mainView.addSubview(imgView)

        let ss = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 50))
        imgView.backgroundColor  = .green
        mainView.addSubview(ss)


        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true


        ss.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ss.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = false
        ss.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        ss.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true

        if lastImage != nil {

            ss.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.topAnchor , constant: 20).isActive = true

            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 50).isActive = true



        }else{
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true
            ss.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor , constant: 25).isActive = true


        }


        lastImage = imgView
        lastImage2 = ss
        mainView.removeConstraint(mainViewBootom!)


        mainViewBootom = mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage2!.bottomAnchor , constant: 40)




        mainViewBootom!.isActive = true
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple notes...

With proper constraint setup, auto-layout handles the `UIScrollView` content size all by itself. No need to ever set `scrollView.contentSize = ...`

You have several instances of adding a subview (image view) to your `mainView`, which is a subview of your scroll view, but then you add constraints from that subview to your controller's view. Make sure you are constraining elements to the proper other elements.

Here's your code, with commented changes:

```
class BenViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var  lastImage:UIImageView?

// 1) don't need this
//  fileprivate var  lastImage2:UIImageView?

    fileprivate var mainViewBootom:NSLayoutConstraint?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupVIew()
    }

// 2) don't need this
//  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//      scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height)
//      view.layoutIfNeeded()
//  }

    //MARK: Components
    let scrollView:UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
        return sv
    }()

    let mainView:UIView = {
        let uv = UIView()
        uv.backgroundColor = .white
        return uv
    }()

    let btnAdd:UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
        btn.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()



    let textField:UITextField = {
        let jake = UITextField()
        return jake

    }()

    //MARK: Setup UI
    func setupVIew() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(btnAdd)
        view.addSubview(textField)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btnAdd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([




            btnAdd.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            btnAdd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -12),
            btnAdd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            btnAdd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),


            //
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),
            //



            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnAdd.topAnchor , constant: -12),
        ])
        btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClickedAdd), for: .touchUpInside)

        scrollView.addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// 3) change this:
//      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
//          mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
//          mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
//          mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
//      ])
//

// to this
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
        ])
// end of change 3)

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        imgView.backgroundColor  = .red
        mainView.addSubview(imgView)


        let samsam = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 40, height: 100))
        samsam.backgroundColor  = .blue
        mainView.addSubview(samsam)


        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// 4) change view.centerXAnchor to mainView.centerXAnchor
//      imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true


        samsam.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// 5) change view.centerXAnchor to mainView.centerXAnchor
//      samsam.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        samsam.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        samsam.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        samsam.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
        samsam.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true



        if lastImage != nil {
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 20).isActive = true
        }else{
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor , constant: 12).isActive = true
        }
        lastImage = samsam
        mainViewBootom = mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 12)
        mainViewBootom!.isActive = true
    }

    @objc func didClickedAdd(){
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20))
        imgView.backgroundColor  = .orange
        mainView.addSubview(imgView)

        let ss = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 50))

// 6) typo or copy/paste mistake
//      imgView.backgroundColor  = .green
        ss.backgroundColor  = .green

        mainView.addSubview(ss)


        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// 7) change view.centerXAnchor to mainView.centerXAnchor
//      imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true


        ss.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// 8) change view.leadingAnchor to mainView.leadingAnchor
//      ss.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = false
        ss.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor).isActive = false

        ss.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        ss.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true

// 9) always need to do this ... but did you mean imgView.bottomAnchor?
        ss.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.topAnchor , constant: 20).isActive = true

        if lastImage != nil {

            // 9a) instead of only here
            //ss.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.topAnchor , constant: 20).isActive = true

            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor , constant: 50).isActive = true

        }else{

            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor , constant: 10).isActive = true

        }

// 10) always need to do this
        // deactivate bottom constraint
        mainViewBootom?.isActive = false
        lastImage = ss
        mainViewBootom = mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage!.bottomAnchor, constant: 40)
        mainViewBootom?.isActive = true

// 11) don't need any of this
//      lastImage = imgView
//      lastImage2 = ss
//      mainView.removeConstraint(mainViewBootom!)
//
//
//      mainViewBootom = mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lastImage2!.bottomAnchor , constant: 40)
//
//
//
//
//      mainViewBootom!.isActive = true
//      view.layoutIfNeeded()
//
//      scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height)
//      view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode’s “view debugger” (the button is circled in red in my screen snapshot below) and you’ll see what’s going on:

[image]

Your `ss` view has no background color. Note, that when you created that view, you accidentally reset the `imgView` background color a second time rather than setting the `ss.backgroundColor`.

Fix that and you’ll see your both `imgView` and `ss`:

[image]

The view debugger is your best friend when trying to diagnose issues like this. Now, obviously, the green view probably isn’t where you intended it, but you should now be able to see it and diagnose that issue very easily.

---

All of this having been said, a few observations:

1. You’re making life much harder than you need to. If you just set the constraints for the scroll view and a stack view within that scroll view, you then only need to add an arranged subview. For example:

   ```
   @objc func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
   }
   ```

   Note, once the stack view and scroll view have been set up (see below), then you don’t need to mess around with `contentSize` or constraints for these subviews at all (other than the `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor`). The auto layout engine, combined with the constraints between the stack view and the scroll view, will take care of everything for you.

   So, a full working example:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
           let scrollView = UIScrollView()
           scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           return scrollView
       }()

       let stackView: UIStackView = {
           let stackView = UIStackView()
           stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           stackView.axis = .vertical
           stackView.alignment = .center
           stackView.spacing = 10
           return stackView
       }()

       let button: UIButton = {
           let button = UIButton(type: .system)
           button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
           return button
       }()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           configure()
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Actions

   extension ViewController {
       @objc func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
           stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
           stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Private utility methods

   private extension ViewController {
       func configure() {
           view.addSubview(scrollView)
           view.addSubview(button)
           scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               // define frame of `scrollView`

               scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
               scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor),
               scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
               scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

               // define frame of `button`

               button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
               button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

               // define contentSize of `scrollView` based upon size of `stackView`

               stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
               stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
               stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
               stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),

               // but define width of `stackView` relative to the _main view_

               stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
           ])

           button.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
       }

       func randomView() -> UIView {
           let widthRange = view.bounds.width * 0.1 ... view.bounds.width * 0.9
           let heightRange = view.bounds.width * 0.1 ... view.bounds.width * 0.25
           let view = UIView()
           view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: .random(in: widthRange)),
               view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: .random(in: heightRange))
           ])
           view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: .random(in: 0.25...1), green: .random(in: 0.25...1), blue: .random(in: 0.25...1), alpha: 1)
           return view
       }
   }
   ```
2. Even better, I’d personally set up the scroll view, stack view, button, and all the associated constraints in Interface Builder, and then that hairy `configure` method in my example goes away completely. It’s fun to learn how to create views programmatically, but in real-world projects, it’s rarely the most productive way to do it. Do programmatic views where needed (e.g. adding arranged subviews to the stack view on the click of a button), but otherwise, for those views that should be there when you first run the app, Interface Builder is worth considering.

   E.g. It dramatically reduces the amount of code above, leaving us simply with:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
       @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

       @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
           stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
           stackView.addArrangedSubview(randomView())
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Private utility methods

   private extension ViewController {
       func randomView() -> UIView { ... }
   }
   ```

   Clearly, it takes a while to get used to designing views and configuring constraints in IB, but it’s worth the effort. It distills our code down the the bare essentials.
3. In your code, you’re setting frames for these image views and then setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. There’s absolutely no point in setting the `frame` in that case, because `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` says “ignore my `frame`, use constraints instead.”
4. I’m assuming you’re doing all of this just to become familiar with scroll views, but it’s worth noting that, especially when adding lots of image views, that the scroll view is an inherently inefficient approach.

   For example, let’s say you’ve added 100 image views, but you can see only 8 at a time. Do you really want to hold all 100 image views in memory at the same time? No.

   But, `UITableView`, which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, takes care of this. You end up only keeping the currently visible image views in memory. It’s a far better approach.

   This is especially true when you start using actual `UIImage` objects, because they require a lot of memory. We get lulled into a sense of security, looking at reasonably sized PNG/JPG assets, but when they’re loaded into memory, they’re uncompressed and require a disproportionate amount of memory.